# After adding a permission, why do I need to re-query for the Django user to see the added permission?

Tags: django, permissions

In the following `Django manage.py` shell session, why don't I see the permission that I added to my user object until I do a new query for that user?

```
In [16]: john = User.objects.create_user(username='john')

In [17]: john
Out[17]: <User: john>

In [18]: john.get_all_permissions()
Out[18]: set([])

In [19]: john.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename='add_user'))

In [20]: john.get_all_permissions()
Out[20]: set([])   <== I expected to see the new permission here.  Why not?

In [21]: john = User.objects.get(username='john')

In [22]: john.get_all_permissions()
Out[22]: set([u'auth.add_user'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does caching of permissions the first time you request them for a given user instance, it stores them against `_perm_cache` on the user object, this is to prevent excessive database lookup when checking permissions which might happen numerous times during a request (especially during template rendering where you might have permission checks around forms and links).

You've identified one solution to your problem, which is reloading the user from the database. the other is to delete `_perm_cache` (and `_group_perm_cache` if you want to be thorough) from the user object:

```
del john._perm_cache
del john._group_perm_cache
```